# Extract table data using split of column values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table data as

```
col1    col2    col3   col4
11       12     xx yy    20
22       13     qq aa    21
```

my TDD requried using TSQL as

```
col1     col2    col3    col4
11       12       xx      20
11       12       yy      20
22       13       qq      21
22       13       aa      21
```

basically, col3 is having values with space, need to create the rows for each value separed by space value.

thanks
prav

Comment: Is the 3rd column consistent? 2 characters followed by a space, then two more characters? If so, then your solution is fairly simple - two inserts using a substring for that 3rd column. If not, you'll have to do something a bit more complex - like use a tally table to find the values on either side of the space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at something like this

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        col1 INT,
        col2 INT,
        col3 VARCHAR(50),
        col4 INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT  11,12,'xx yy',20  
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT  22,13,'qq aa',21

;WITH Vals AS (
    SELECT  *,
            CAST('<d>' + REPLACE(col3, ' ', '</d><d>') + '</d>' AS XML) XMLCol
    FROM    @Table
)
SELECT  Vals.*,
        T.split.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') SplitValue
FROM    Vals
CROSS APPLY
        XMLCol.nodes('/d') T(split)
```

Comment: I'm not good enough with XML to know if this compiles and runs as you have it, but if it does - then nice job!